# Compare two IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ienumerable

I have two Ienumerables. First consist volleyball,basketboll, soccer events.
Second - full history of games. Its all string, because I parse its

```
public class Events
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string FirstTeam { get; set; }
        public string SecondTeam { get; set; }
    }

public class History
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string FirstTeam { get; set; }
        public string FirstTeamGoals { get; set; }
        public string SecondTeam { get; set; }
        public string SecondteamGoals { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to show previous games of team, which takes part in event. Team can be First or Second team in previous games.

I try this:

```
foreach (var teamInEvent in ListEvents)
            {
                var firstor = from p in History
                where p.FirstTeam == teamInEvent.FirstTeam || p.SecondTeam == teamInEvent.FirstTeam
                where p.SecondTeam == teamInEvent.SecondTeam || p.FirstTeam == teamInEvent.SecondTeam 
                select p;    
            }
```

as a result I need to show Date,FirstTeam,FirstTeamGoals,SecondTeam,SectGoals. Compare goals and show: Team won last 3 games(for example).

Comment: Your `Date` property should be typeof `DateTime` and your `FirstTeamGoals` and `SecondteamGoals` need to be typeof `int` (you not going to be able to compare anything using `string`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem "first team" and "second team" do not differ semantically. If that is the case you need to include records where the first team is listed as "second" and vice versa.

```
IQueriable<History> GetHistory(Events teamInEvent)
{
    // Normal Query
    var firstQuery = 
    from h1 in History
    select h1 
    where h1.FirstTeam == teamInEvent.FirstTeam || 
          h1.SecondTeam == teamInEvent.SecondTeam;

    // Query with the first and the second team fields swapped
    var secondQuery = 
    from h2 in History
    select new History { Date = h2.Date, 
                         FirstTeam = h2.SecondTeam, 
                         FirstTeamGoals = h2.SecondTeamGoals, 
                         SecondTeam = h2.FirstTeam,
                         SecondTeamGoals = h2.FirstTeamGoals 
                       }
    where h2.FirstTeam == teamInEvent.SecondTeam || 
          h2.SecondTeam == teamInEvent.FirstTeam;


   // Stitch two queries together
   return firstQuery.Concat(secondQuery);
}
```

The above function returns a result set for a given entry in `Events`

To consolidate all entries simply iterate the events adding results to a list:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<Events, History[]>;
foreach (var teamInEvent in ListEvents)
{
    var item = Tuple.Create(teamInEvent, GetHistory(teamInEvent).ToArray());
    list.Add(item);
}
```

Instead of merely storing historical data you can process the history computing the stats you need.

```
foreach (var teamInEvent in ListEvents)
{
    var history = GetHistory(teamInEvent);
    var stats   = ComputeStats(teamInEvent, history); 
    list.Add(Tuple.Create(teamEvent, stats));
}
```